# Validar input para coincidir solo letras de la A a la Z incluyendo la ñ

Tags: javascript, html

Me preguntaba si podría conseguir validar un input que coincidiera con cadenas que sólo tuviera caracteres alfabéticos incluyendo la ñ y si es posible con tildes.

Comment: Hola Ricardo, por favor incluye más información en la pregunta: ¿en qué lenguaje lo quieres hacer: HTML o JS? ¿qué has intentado hasta ahora? ¿con qué problemas te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio).

Comment: Puedes usar regex

Comment: Sí, podrías conseguirlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa expresiones regulares, aquí puedes verificar mediante expresiones lo que quieras validar

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions

/[ñ+a-z]/gi

con i es insensitivo a las mayusculas

Aquí puedes prácticar https://regexr.com/